# Is Yammer API redirection temporary or permanent?

Tags: android, api, yammer

I have been creating an android app which calls the Yammer API to retrieve files from Yammer.

Recently, I found out that the original yammer file link (https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/uploaded_files/) is now redirected to the new url
(https://files.yammerusercontent.com/v2/files/).

All the file API calls are broken in my app, and I have managed to fix it by getting the redirected URL (its 307 redirection) and re-grab the file from the new URL. As 307 redirection is temporary redirection, does anyone know whether it is just a temporary change, or it works this way from now?

I have not released my fixed app into production yet as I am not sure whether this change will take place

There's nothing mentioned in Yammer API guideline about the new yammerusercontent.com domain either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files endpoint that you are using isn't documented currently, so effectively it is unsupported and may not have been communicated to developers the way it was to end users. You can use this at your own risk, but you may need to have good integration tests to check for changes. Also keep an eye on the Yammer [requirements](https://about.yammer.com/success/activate/admin-guide/the-basics/browser-and-system-requirements/) page.

The *.yammerusercontent.com has been documented in the [Yammer requirements](https://about.yammer.com/success/activate/admin-guide/the-basics/browser-and-system-requirements/) for quite some time, and there was a more recent [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2967488) which covered the change as the Yammer web application switched to using files.yammerusercontent.com. Using a domain like this is a pretty common technique for protecting users from different attacks using uploaded content and many SaaS products do this - so it's going to be used going forward.